# Run an html form On a gwt Widget

Tags: java, gwt, uibinder

is there any suggestions about how to run an HTML Form On a gwt Wedget??

I read about:
1- HTML Widget which didn't work (just inserted the code in the constructore)
2- uiBinder (can i run a form using this?)

Comment: What does it means : run an html form ?  
Do you want to submit an html form ?

Comment: yes .. i need to run this on a panel :
 `<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/EmployeesDataFileUpload" name = "f">
  <h2>please enter the Employees Data file to upload:<br/><input type="file" name="upfile"><br/>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Press"> to upload Employees Data file </h2> 
</form>
`

Comment: thanks for your comment .. it worked out with the Form Panel .. Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FormPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html) to send a form to the server